# Finding an efficient function for deciding the position of a square in front of a robots current position

Tags: java, performance, methods, formula

In my programme, my robot has a heading defined as an integer value, 0 for east, 1 for south, 2 for west and 3 for north. Also I have a 2D array grid[y][x] which contains information on the square in position (x, y). (0,0) is the position of the bottom left square in the grid.

My question is, if I know my robots heading is east(for example) then how can I efficiently locate the square in front of the robot. I don't want to just use a switch statement by defining the next square for each of the four headings, since I need to use this method in my code quite often and it would be nice to have an efficient implementation of it.

After using a simple switch statement I tried the following(the robot is in position (x,y)):

```
if(heading%2 == 0)
//then position in front of robot is (x + (heading+2)%4 - 1, y)
if(heading%2 == 1)
//then position in front of robot is (x, y + heading - 2)
```

The code works for finding the position in the grid in front of the robot depending on the integer value of the heading and has been slimmed down to 2 cases. Is there any possible method for finding the position in front of the robot without the need of using cases. Preferably one which doesn't require me to change the values for the headings east,south, north, west.

Comment: Why not just do this once, encapsulate it into a method, then feed the heading in with a parameter to the method. Then you don't have repeating code, and can use the idea of OOP like its intended.

Comment: What's inefficient about `switch`?

Comment: I need to find the position ahead of the robot several times, and the example I gave only checks two cases rather than 4 with a normal switch

Comment: @DavidJones I've already implemented that, but I was wondering if someone could help me come up with a different formula which doesn't require separate cases

Comment: intuitively I'm looking for a formula f, such that f(x,y,heading)=(x+xIncrement, y+yIncrement). But my example gives two different formulas for two different cases

Comment: where xIncrement and yIncrement are two values calculated using the heading value.